How to access Polars Dataframe containing Struct Type column fields using SQLContext?
I'm trying to execute SQL query on Polars dataframes using SQLContext and below is my code:
 ctx = pl.SQLContext().register_many(
        {"tbl1": df_source, "tbl2": df_reference})

src_df = ctx.execute(pl_sql_query, eager=True)

Here the schema of df_source contains a column named json_message of type Struct with Key Value pairs i.e.,
('json_message', Struct({'id': Int64, 'name': String, 'age': Int64, 'dob': String}))

My sql query to access the struct field is:
pl_sql_query = 
"select json_message.id as id, json_message.name as name 
from tbl1 
where json_message.id in (select id from tbl2)"

When i execute this query, i'm getting an exception no table or alias named 'json_message' found
Not sure how exactly we need to access the struct field value. Tried struct.with_fields but not able to access the value.
Can someone please help me on this?

IDK if it's possible, but I would suggest you to open an issue in the polars repository.

Thanks for making the issue; I have just landed a PR that addresses this, enabling Polars struct-field access via the SQL interface: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/17109 

Thank you for everything you are doing for polars. Such an awesome library :)

You're very welcome. This just merged, and will be available in the (imminent/upcoming) 1.0 release.

Unfortunately this doesn't look to be possible in Polars at the moment. However, the SQL functionality is being quite actively developed, so I would think this would be an accepted feature request. I will make it over the next few days if you don't get there first.
EDIT: I see that you've created a feature request and already mentioned there that you are using DuckDB as a workaround.
As for a workaround until (hopefully) this is implemented natively in Polars, DuckDB is probably the best option.
import duckdb
import polars as pl

df_source = pl.DataFrame({
    "json_message": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Manuel Neuer",
        "age": 38,
        "dob": "1986-03-27",
    }
})
df_reference = pl.DataFrame({"id": 1})

# I updated the SQL to refer to `df_source` and `df_reference`
# as DuckDB checks variables in scope. `.pl()` converts back to Polars.
duckdb.sql(
    """
    select json_message.id as id, json_message.name as name 
    from df_source 
    where json_message.id in (select id from df_reference)
    """
).pl()
# ┌─────┬──────────────┐
# │ id  ┆ name         │
# │ --- ┆ ---          │
# │ i64 ┆ str          │
# ╞═════╪══════════════╡
# │ 1   ┆ Manuel Neuer │
# └─────┴──────────────┘

P.S. Including a fully reproducible example will save people having to come up  with dummy data and will make it even easier to help you!

Hi @Henry Harbeck it will be really helpful if we could get this supported by polars please as using DuckDb, sometimes it throws memory errors. Thanks again for considering and accepting this as a feature request.

Hi @BalajiVenkatachalam, yes I 100% agree. Especially given that Structs are native types in Polars, I imagine this will be accepted without any concerns. Just to be clear though, it is up to the Polars maintainers to accept the issue (and I am not one).
Also linking the github request if anyone is looking in the future
https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/16651
